# RobotFramework : Query xml database : Not able to do a validation on the result set

Tags: robotframework, xml-database

When I do a query against xml database and getting the query results as `[('Testing',)]`. I want to do a simple check against this value to make sure it is same as what's being entered via UI .

```
Should be equal     ${queryResults}     Testing
```

But I am getting an error `[('Testing',)] != Testing`

Any idea what I am doing wrong here . Is there a way to get the value stripped out of all these symbols `( , ' , ??`

Comment: Can you provide the example code that creates/fills the `${queryResults}` variable? The best approach is not to filter the variable after the fact, but to make sure your result is correct in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of a query in the database library is a list of tuples - each list member is a response row, and the tuple is the column values in it.
Why? Because being a list you get them in the same order as the DB returned them, and a tuple - because it's a read-only object *(this format actually comes from python's standard db protocol, not from RF's db library itself)*.

To get the value you're after you have to "unpack" the object; presuming you want to get the first column from the first row, that is the simplest approach:

```
${db value}=    Set Variable    ${queryResults[0][0]}
```

The first index is the row number, the second - the column.
Then you can compare `${db value}` with your expected value.

Keep a couple of things in mind - the access indices of ordered object (lists, tuples) start from 0; and if there is no element at the index you specify - e.g. there was no such row or column in the DB response - this will cause an exception - a fail status in Robotframework.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Will try this way.